# What resistances does an Imp have in recent printings of the Monster Manual?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, damage-resistance, errata

My copy of the *Player's Handbook* and my copy of the *Monster Manual* both state that an Imp has resistance to:

> [...] bludgeoning, piercing, and slashing from nonmagical weapons that aren't silvered.

And then [DnD Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/imp) (without buying any books there) states:

> [...] Bludgeoning, Piercing, and Slashing from Nonmagical Attacks that aren't Silvered

Meanwhile the [*Player's Handbook* errata](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/PH-Errata.pdf) states:

> [...] bludgeoning, piercing, and slashing from nonmagical attacks not made with silvered weapons.

And the [*Monster Manual* errata](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/MM-Errata.pdf) states:

> Throughout the book, instances of “nonmagical weapons” in Damage Resistances/Immunities entries have been replaced with “nonmagical attacks.”

Applying this exact update would make *my* book state:

> [...] bludgeoning, piercing, and slashing from nonmagical attacks that aren't silvered.

This matches DnD Beyond's description but "attacks that aren't silvered" sounds very off/wrong to me. I have no idea if this wording actually exists in the printings of the *Monster Manual*, it is just what the errata states.

---

Which of these wordings, if any, is correct; what is the wording in more/most recent printings of the *Monster Manual*? If this wording conflicts with the *Player's Handbook* errata, which one takes precedence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## "[...] from nonmagical attacks that aren’t silvered"

At least as of the 2018 printing of the physical *Monster Manual*, its resistances read (p. 76):

> **Damage Resistances** cold; bludgeoning, piercing, and slashing from nonmagical attacks that aren’t silvered

This matches the most recent [version of the imp statblock in the MM compendium on D&D Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/mm/monsters-d#_idContainer350), as well as the version on [p. 277 of the SRD (last updated in 2016)](https://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SRD-OGL_V5.1.pdf#page=277).

The MM errata PDF correctly describes the change, at least in this case.

Note that even though the errata PDF for the *Player's Handbook* says the imp's resistances now read "bludgeoning, piercing, and slashing from nonmagical attacks not made with silvered weapons", the 2018 printing of the physical *Player's Handbook* (p. 306) includes the exact same quote as the one above from the *Monster Manual*. Thus, the PHB errata PDF is inaccurate.

It looks like the [version in the PHB compendium on DDB](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/appendix-d-creature-statistics#CreaturesFI) is actually (currently) inaccurate, and matches the incorrect quote from the PHB errata PDF rather than the actual quote in the physical PHB. In contrast, [the statblock in the "basic rules" compendium on DDB](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/monster-stat-blocks-i#_idContainer350) accurately reflects the version in the SRD (and the physical PHB and MM).

Comment: @Medix2: There are no mechanics for silvering anything that isn't a weapon, so there's no meaningful difference.